# How optional arguments works in Python

Tags: python, func

I've been reading a book, and got stuck on the topic of optional arguments.

• Can define defaults for arguments that need not be
passed

```
>>> def func(a, b, c=10, d=100):
    print a, b, c, d

>>> func(1,2)
   1 2 10 100
```

I don't get this ... how? Spent the hour googling and cannot understand it.

Reading this book and on that topic. I just do not get why `func(1,2)` gives me `1,2,10,100`. I mean, how does it know?

Comment: Default arguments (thos that have an = sign after them and specify a value) are optional. If you don't specify the value, they take the one defined on the function definition.

Comment: ah ok. so this is a default thing? If possible, could you give an example on how to use it in practise? Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to understand topics like this is to experiment in an IDE.

```
def func(a, b, c=10, d=100):
    pass
```

If you call `func` with 2 arguments (like you have in your example) then `c` and `d` use their default arguments, which are specified in the function signature above.p

You can override the defaults simply by specifying them - take this example where I'm sending 3 arguments to this function

```
>>> func(1,2,3)
<<< 1 2 3 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't formally define `c` and `d`, the call becomes:

> func(1,2,10,100)

If you don't formally define `d`, the call `func(1,2,5)` is identical to:

> func(1,2,5,100)

Hope that helps...

Comment: HTH, mate, I'd also suggest upvoting answers you found helpful.